# Docker not starting because there isn't space on server

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, sudo

I'm trying to start up my docker but upon investigation I realized it can't start because there isn't enough space on the server. I would have run the `sudo docker system prune -a -f --volumes` command but it won't go through because docker isn't running and most of the space is taken by docker images and logs. Where can I find these logs and dangling images to delete on the server manually?

Comment: `/var/lib/docker`. Especially `/var/lib/docker/image`, `/var/lib/docker/containers` and `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. Be careful what you do with these.

Comment: Thanks @ashu that helped!